# cannot use gvim when project compiles

Tags: c++, vim, makefile

When I call `:make` on VIM all my projects freezes until the compilation ends so I cannot doing any work until that finishes. On top of that the project  I am working now is very big.

Is there anyway to edit other files while the compilation is in progress aside from opening other instances?

I am using `gvim` under linux compiling `C++` code with `gcc`.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Tim Pope's [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:make` command is synchronous because Vim needs to wait in order to parse the compilation output for the *quickfix window*.

If you don't use the quickfix functionality, you can trigger your build via `:! ... &` instead, or modify `'makeprg'` to spawn a new shell for compilation (also by appending `&`, assuming a Unixoid system).

To keep Vim from blocking *and* have a quickfix error list, you have to manually read the error file via `:cfile buildoutput` *after* the build is finished.